# Create binding in code from xml data

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, xaml

I want to bind data from sample data to code in c#. I am not getting exact output when tried different models available online. I want to do arithmetic operation between two values from data table.
My xml data looks like this:

```
<SampleData:data xmlns:SampleData="clr-namespace:Expression.Blend.SampleData.data"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <SampleData:data.factors>
        <SampleData:cfsItem col1="item1" item1="1" item2="2" />
        <SampleData:cfsItem col2="item2" item2="3" item2="4" />
    </SampleData:data.factors>
</SampleData:data>
```

I want to select the value with a LINQ query; i.e selecting col1 from table 'factors' in data and compare it with value returned from listbox element.

```
private void ListBox1_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxItem selected = ListBox1.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;
    string y = selected.Content as string;
    this.DataContext = from factors in data
                       where col1.factors == y
                       select item1;
}
```

Can anyone help me out of this? Thank you!

Comment: We can't help you unless you tell us what the problem is. What is the expected outcome, what is the actual outcome?

Comment: I am doing conversions application. I need to select the item from a list box. It will be copied as a selected item from listbox. this will be compared to items in database and the conversion factor will be selected using a LINQ query at particular item.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `data` object is a single item and that you're really looking for `factors` inside `data`.
Based on what you show you would probably need the following to select the `factors` based on the `ListBox.SelectedItem`'s content compared to the `col1` property.

Just as a note: I think you meant the first `item2` in the second record to really mean `item1`. If so the following would apply:

```
private void ListBox1_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItem = (ListBoxItem)ListBox1.SelectedItem;
    if (selectedItem != null)
    {
        var y = (string)selectedItem.Content;
        var filteredFactors = (from factor in data.factors
                               where factor.col1 == y
                               select factor.Item1);
        //filteredFactors is IEnumerable
        this.DataContext = filteredFactors;
        // if you need the first only or nothing if there is none.
        this.DataContext = filteredFactors.FirstOrDefault();
        // if there can be nothing or only one
        this.DataContext = filteredFactors.SingleOrDefault();
    }
}
```

In the example above I selected only `item1` of the filtered `factors`.
If you want to return the entire record you would remove `.item1` in the query.

```
var filteredFactors = (from factor in data.factors
                       where factor.col1 == y
                       select factor);
```

You'll probably notice I have used the keyword `var` multiple times. I like to use it if it improves readability. see [Implicitly Typed Local Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx) if you're interested.